# Azimuth/Altitude discrepancy between PyEphem and Skyfield

Tags: pyephem, skyfield

I cannot resolve why I am getting a different azimuth/altitude for a comet calculation between PyEphem and Skyfield, yet the right ascension and declination match.

Code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


# External verification:
# https://in-the-sky.org/data/object.php?id=0088P
# https://theskylive.com/88p-info
# https://heavens-above.com/comet.aspx?cid=88P
# https://www.calsky.com/cs.cgi/Comets/3?


import datetime, ephem, io, skyfield.api, skyfield.constants, skyfield.data.mpc


now = datetime.datetime.strptime( "2020-07-22", "%Y-%m-%d" )
latitude = -33
longitude = 151

cometName = "88P/Howell"

# https://minorplanetcenter.net/iau/Ephemerides/Comets/Soft03Cmt.txt
cometDataPyEphem = "88P/Howell,e,4.3838,56.6855,235.9159,3.105737,0.1800765,0.56433120,347.8225,07/21.0/2020,2000,g 11.0,6.0"

# https://minorplanetcenter.net/iau/Ephemerides/Comets/Soft00Cmt.txt
cometDataSkyfield = "0088P         2020 09 26.6241  1.353073  0.564331  235.9159   56.6855    4.3838  20200721  11.0  6.0  88P/Howell                                               MPEC 2019-JE2"


print( "PyEphem:", ephem.__version__ )
print( "Skyfield:", skyfield.__version__ )


# PyEphem
observer = ephem.Observer()
observer.date = ephem.Date( now )
observer.lat = latitude
observer.lon = longitude

body = ephem.readdb( cometDataPyEphem )
body.compute( observer )

print( "PyEphem comet", cometName,
       "\n\tLat:", observer.lat,
       "\n\tLon:", observer.lon,
       "\n\tAlt:", body.alt,
       "\n\tRA:", body.ra,
       "\n\tDec:", body.dec )


# Skyfield
timeScale = skyfield.api.load.timescale( builtin = True )
topos = skyfield.api.Topos( latitude_degrees = latitude, longitude_degrees = longitude )
ephemeris = skyfield.api.load( "de421.bsp" )

with io.BytesIO( cometDataSkyfield.encode() ) as f:
    dataframe = skyfield.data.mpc.load_comets_dataframe( f ).set_index( "designation", drop = False )

sun = ephemeris[ "sun" ]
earth = ephemeris[ "earth" ]
body = sun + skyfield.data.mpc.comet_orbit( dataframe.loc[ cometName ], timeScale, skyfield.constants.GM_SUN_Pitjeva_2005_km3_s2 )

t = timeScale.utc( now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second )
alt, az, bodyDistanceToEarth = ( earth + topos ).at( t ).observe( body ).apparent().altaz()
ra, dec, bodyDistanceToEarth = ( earth + topos ).at( t ).observe( body ).radec()

print( "Skyfield comet", cometName,
       "\n\tAz:", az, 
       "\n\tAlt:", alt, 
       "\n\tRA:", ra, 
       "\n\tDec:", dec )
```

The RA/Dec match between PyEphem and Skfield and also with several websites (see the comment section at the top).  Whilst the Skyfield values for Az/Alt are somewhat close to that given by [Heavens Above](https://heavens-above.com/comet.aspx?cid=88P), I cannot determine why the discrepancy between PyEphem and Skyfield for Az/Alt.

EDIT:  Amend the script to print out lat/lon and sample (correct) results:

```
PyEphem: 3.7.6.0
Skyfield: 1.24
PyEphem comet 88P/Howell 
    Lat: -33:00:00.0 
    Lon: 151:00:00.0 
    Az: 109:52:54.6 
    Alt: -11:19:11.4 
    RA: 13:27:08.32 
    Dec: -9:56:54.6 
Skyfield comet 88P/Howell 
    Lat: -33deg 00' 00.0" 
    Lon: 151deg 00' 00.0" 
    Az: 109deg 53' 03.4" 
    Alt: -11deg 19' 23.4" 
    RA: 13h 26m 04.51s 
    Dec: -09deg 50' 37.9"
```

Comment: Could you include the program's output in your question? That would help folks get an idea of the size of the discrepancy, even who don't have the software installed to run the code for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try printing out the PyEphem observer location:

```
print(observer.lat)
print(observer.lon)
```

you will find that your observer's coordinates are otherwise than you expect:

```
-1890:45:38.6
8651:39:45.7
```

That's because PyEphem interprets floating-point angles as radians, which is how your numbers `-33` and `151` are being interpreted. To have PyEphem interpret them as degrees, send strings instead:

```
observer.lat = str(latitude)
observer.lon = str(longitude)
```

The script should then show very close agreement between the two libraries.

I now consider it a mistake for PyEphem to have tried making it so “convenient” to switch between degrees and radians, but it cannot be fixed without breaking all existing PyEphem scripts. So I wrote Skyfield, which never makes odd decisions based on type, and always tries to label values `degrees` or `radians` so that it's clear to the programmer what units are expected.

Comment: Thanks Brandon; should have known this but was fixated on looking at the Az/Alt!  One thing that that does not make sense: despite the lat/long being so out of whack, why does the RA/Dec match for both PyEphem and Skyfield?

Comment: Because the comet is at the same place in the sky, against the same stars and constellation, for everyone on Earth.